# The longest increasing subsequence of a reversed sequence and a negated sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let's say you have a sequence $A$, for example $1, 5, 2, 3, 6$.

You take the reversed sequence: $6, 3, 2, 5, 1$

and the negated sequence: $-1, -5, -2, -3, -6$

and find the length of the longest increasing subsequence of each.

In both cases, the answer is $2$.

How would you prove that this will always hold: The length LIS of the reversed of A and the negated sequence of A will always be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both negation and reversal turn decreasing subsequences into increasing subsequences (and back). So both results are the length of the longest decreasing subsequence in the original sequence.